# python3: doctest helper/internal functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, doctest

How do I make the following work so that helpers's test is run? It doesen't.

```
def B():
    def helper():
        """
        >>> some doctest
        result
        """

...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nested functions cannot be found, because the function object doesn't *exist* until the `B()` function is run. You'd have to *return* it as the result of calling the `B()` function, then assign it to the `__test__` dictionary:

```
def B()
    def helper()
        """
        >>> some doctest
        result
        """

    return helper    

# ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    __test__ = {'helper': B()}
    doctest.testmod()
```

`doctest.testmod()` looks for the `__test__` global dictionary and looks for docstrings on any classes, methods, functions and modules in the values; any string values are directly executed as docstring tests.

If `B()` does *other* things besides, then you probably should make `helper()` a simple global function instead:

```
def B():
    # uses helper

def helper()
    """
    >>> some doctest
    result
    """

# ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```